# Android: Record and play video in the same SurfaceView

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, surfaceview, android-mediarecorder

I want to see the video that I'm currently recording in a SurfaceView and if the recodring finished I wanto to replay the video in the same SurfaceView.
Even though I thought it would be a common feature in Apps, I couldn't find any example and couldn't make my code work.

```
private void prepareRecorder() {
try {
    recorder = new MediaRecorder();
    recorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());

    camera.unlock();
    recorder.setCamera(camera);

    recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
    recorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);

    camcorderProfile = CamcorderProfile.get(CamcorderProfile.QUALITY_LOW);
    recorder.setProfile(camcorderProfile);

    File newFile = new File(videoFilePath);

    recorder.setOutputFile(newFile.getAbsolutePath());

    try {
        recorder.prepare();
    } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}catch(Exception e){
    releaseCamera();
}
}
```

//

```
public void onClick(View v) {


    if(mediaPlayer!=null) {
        mediaPlayer.reset();
        mediaPlayer.release();
    }
    mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();



    try {
        mediaPlayer.setDataSource(videoFile.getAbsolutePath());
        SurfaceView surfaceView = (SurfaceView) getView().findViewById(R.id.videoInvitationFragSurfaceView);

        mediaPlayer.setSurface(surfaceView.getHolder().getSurface());
        mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

If I just record the video my code works, if just play the video it works as well. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance

Edit: As a current workaround I use two SurfaceViews and "hide" them  (set size to 0) if needed

Comment: I am having the same issue, any new solutions or just the workaround? Can you show all your code too please, what is the onClick from?

Comment: I'm still using the workaround with two surfaceviews. When I click on the play button I shrink the first surfaceview via Surfaceview.setFixedSize(0,0) and expand the second one in the same way

Answer (score 0):

> If I just record the video my code works, if just play the video it works as well. Any ideas?

As much I understand, you can reuse same surface view only after it is destroyed and regenerated, i.e you can reuse same SurfaceView only after `surfaceDestroyed()` is called and then `surfaceCreated()` is called only after this destroy and create cycle you can reuse SurfaceView.

To achive this all you have to do is: after video recording is done set SurfaceView visibility to GONE which will ensure `surfaceDestroyed()` call back and again set SurfaceView visibility to VISIBLE which will call `surfaceCreated()` after that start video playback.

This is very cumbersome process so I used same SurfaceView for recording and playback in following way:

1. when Activity is created check if VideoFile is available in Intent
2. if yes use `SurfaceView` for playback
3. now if user deletes video restart activity
4. As VideoFile is not found in intent use `SurfaceView` for recording
5. Once recording is done and user want to playback video restart
   Activity with VideoFile information attached in Intent